# Qt libraries for closed C++ applications

Tags: c++, qt

I would start using C++ and develop commercials application with GUI. I found Qt libraries and seem that are good for my software.

I saw that Qt has LGPL license, I read that the license allow the developer to create an application and release it with different license, but I don't understand if at the moment I can develop a commercial C++ windows application (closed source) with Qt **WITHOUT** pay for the Commercial license.

Could someone clarify this point?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LGPL licence means you can use Qt in a commercial application if, and only if, you dynamically link to it. That means using a DLL (or equivalent for your platform) rather than a static library. As long as you do this you can apply whatever licence you like to your actual application.

Look at the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGPL) for more information on the LGPL.

Answer (score 0):

if you do so, you have to provide a way to get the source of the libraries under lgpl you are using.